# Drawing in particular area of HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

If a lot of my drawings are going to be within a particular area of my larger canvas (in this case, in the center), is there a way to just say that you're working within that particular 'sub-canvas' instead of having to add/subtract the margins every time you want to draw? It just makes my code look a lot more complicated every time I'm specifying coordinates.

Comment: May you probably want to use [`Canvas#translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Transformations#Translating) perhaps?

Comment: What alex said and what Alexander tried to say--use context.translate(x,y) to set your new drawings to the "sub-canvas" coordinates.  Notice that after context.translate(100,100) a rectangle drawn with context.rect(0,0,50,50) will actually draw on the canvas at 100,100--nice and simple!

Comment: @markE I'm relying on the canvas width and height to know where to draw, so if I use translate, I will still need to add/subtract the margins to get the "sub-canvas" width and height in order to get my drawing coordinates.

Comment: Perhaps it's the GREAT family dinner I just had that's clouding my brain, but I've always found a translate() simplifies my subsequent drawings because I can draw in "localized" coordinates.  Could you provide some code to clear my "cheesecaked" mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the coordinates' origin using [`translate()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-translate).

First, save the original origin using [`save()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-save). Then, find the origin that suits the centre of your screen's drawing area and call `translate(x, y)`. Do your drawing, and then use [`restore()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-restore) to get your previous origin back.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPffV/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use drawimage to draw an offscreen canvas to a certain part of another canvas.

Create a new canvas object and draw all your stuff to that. In the end draw that canvas to your onscreen canvas with drawimage at some coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

[Kinetic.js](http://kineticjs.com/), a popular library for Canvas allows you to create a `Group` layer.  You can specify the `x`, `y` coordinates, height and width of this `Group`. You can also add shapes and draw other things within this group.

Here's and example:

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });
  var shapesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  /*
   * create a group which will be used to combine
   * multiple simple shapes.  Transforming the group will
   * transform all of the simple shapes together as
   * one unit
   */
  var group = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 220,
    y: 40,
    rotationDeg: 20
  });

  var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'];

  for(var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    // anonymous function to induce scope
    (function() {
      var i = n;
      var box = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: i * 30,
        y: i * 18,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        name: colors[i],
        fill: colors[i],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      });

      group.add(box);
    })();
  }

  shapesLayer.add(group);
  stage.add(shapesLayer);
```

[Here's a tutorial on how to add Groups](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-complex-shapes-using-groups-with-kineticjs/)